# What am I? I advise you to not think abstractly unless directed to do so

Tags: riddle, word

> - My orientation changes, but contextually I stay the same.
> - Some prefer me in seconds because I tend to have an easier time opening up.
> - I stay the same, yet I am always becoming.
> - I sometimes have a lot to say, but my rhetoric is rarely duplicated.
> - I am often ignored in youth but find an audience in time.
> - Some come to me for advice, but my dialogue is often finished upon arrival.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 4):

Could you be

> Death

My orientation changes, but contextually I stay the same.

> Different people look in different ways at the concept op death, but in the end it means your life ends.

Some prefer me in seconds because I tend to have an easier time opening up.

> I think people who are close to death see the time ticking away, could also be towards people who are in a near death situation say they see everything coming towards them in slow motion as there life flashes before them.

I stay the same, yet I am always becoming.

> Not sure think that we all die different ways but in the end it all ends with us being death no matter how you died it's the same.

I sometimes have a lot to say, but my rhetoric is rarely duplicated.

> Also not sure but I think, that death still has a lot of unanswered questions for which people are still looking. So death can give us a lot of answers but it's pretty hard to get the answers regarding death.

I am often ignored in youth but find an audience in time.

> the older you get the more you think about death.

Some come to me for advice, but my dialogue is often finished upon arrival.

> bit morbid, but maybe suicide people who are tired of life seek for "advice" in death, but since you die the dialogue probably ends there as we don't know if anything is beyond.

Comment: Judging from the title, this answer might be a bit too abstract ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Hmm you might be correct on this, I'm not very good at judging what people find abstract these days. I think death as in a death body not so abstract, but the meaning behind death could be very abstract.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be

> A Rotating Black Hole

My orientation changes, but contextually I stay the same.

> The orientation here is that of the axis of rotation which is relative to the Earth. Obviously will be different for different black holes.

Some prefer me in seconds because I tend to have an easier time opening up.

> This is possibly referring to the celestial angle which will be more easily measured in seconds. Because these objects are many lightyears away, they won't tend to move very much in the sky but, with refinement of our measurement to seconds, we can probably more easily detect any changes.

I stay the same, yet I am always becoming.

> Black holes do not change, however a rotating black hole gradually loses its rotational energy over time and becomes a Schwarzschild black hole (though there is no difference in appearance).

I sometimes have a lot to say, but my rhetoric is rarely duplicated.

> I think this is referring to black hole accretion as observed, for example, from active galactic nuclei. I think the lack of duplication is referring to the range of frequencies observed which should vary over time.

I am often ignored in youth but find an audience in time.

> Black holes are difficult to observe and are far away so it does take time before an entity can be classed as observed.

Some come to me for advice, but my dialogue is often finished upon arrival.

> Because these objects are so far away the signal is usually completed by the time it reaches Earth.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> a clock?

My orientation changes, but contextually I stay the same.

> Clock hands are always moving but a clock is always a clock.

Some prefer me in seconds because I tend to have an easier time opening up.

> "seconds" passes faster than minutes or hours.

I stay the same, yet I am always becoming.

> Similar to the first sentence

I sometimes have a lot to say, but my rhetoric is rarely duplicated.

> The clock face is different almost every time you see.

I am often ignored in youth but find an audience in time.

> "in time" taken literally. Does "often ignored in youth" mean that young people in general are less aware of time passing?

Some come to me for advice, but my dialogue is often finished upon arrival.

> Sometimes people would want to check the time, and they can get what they want with just a glance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> Past experience

My orientation changes, but contextually I stay the same.

> People have different perspectives on past experience, but that doesn't change what happened.

Some prefer me in seconds because I tend to have an easier time opening up.

> ???

I stay the same, yet I am always becoming.

> What has already happened doesn't change, but more past experiences are being created all the time

I sometimes have a lot to say, but my rhetoric is rarely duplicated.

> We can learn a lot from what happened in the past, but history rarely repeats itself.

I am often ignored in youth but find an audience in time.

> The youth don't have much experience to draw upon, whereas older people do.

Some come to me for advice, but my dialogue is often finished upon arrival.

> We can learn a lot from past experience, even though the things we are learning from are over.